# Maven seems ignoring MAVEN_OPTS

Tags: maven, apache-spark

I am actually working with spark and I am trying to increase the heapspace.

I have read several topics and followed them.

I am working on windows and I have set the variable environment : `MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx512m` with `set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx512m` and checked it with `set M`

However, what ever the Xmx value is set to. I have the same error.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: System memory 259522560 must be at least 471859200. Please increase heap size using the --driver-memory option or spark.driver.memory in Spark configuration.
```

Is there a way to check what the maximum heap space of the jvm is?
Or is there a work around while instantiating the spark session? Such as `SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.memory", "512m")` ?

I am actually running maven from the command line `mvn test` on Windows. The tests instantiate a sparkSession which results in the error

As I am coding in scala, for the test plugin I have this :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: What's your working environment? How are you running Maven? Command line? IDE? How did you set MAVEN_OPTS? System variables? IDE settings? When do you get that error? It looks like you're getting it when you run your app. If so, it's not related to Maven. We need to know more to understand what's happening.

Comment: Updating, that's right I didn't tell I was running it with mvn test in command lines

Comment: Are you sure you aren't forking another process to run spark?

Comment: I am not sure to get what you mean by "not forking another process to run spark"? How may I check it? You might have found the answer

Comment: I don't think MAVEN_OPTS has any influence on the execution of Spark. You need to set `spark.driver.memory`, for example in your spark-default.conf file.

Comment: I am running it locally, is `SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.memory", "512m")` is the right way to do it?

Comment: What plugin are you using for running your tests? I guess it would be useful to post the plugin's configuration.

Comment: The `scala-maven-plugin` is used to compile the main code and the test code, but are you sure it also runs the tests too?

Comment: Probably. I have seen 3 ways to set spark.driver.memory so far: in your configuration file, in your command line when running Spark standalone (with `--driver-memory 512m`) or in your code by adding `SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.memory", "1024m")` (That's in Java).

Comment: @LittleSanti You are right, fixed.

Comment: @AlexisDufrenoy The config part is exactly what I tried, I should double check my code then.

Comment: @BlueSheepToken Try with `.config("spark.driver.memory", "1G")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case the cause of your overflow problem was that the scalatest-maven-plugin was forking another JVM, I suggest you include the `argLine` property with the proper `-X` options:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-Xmx512m</argLine>
        ...
    </configuration>
    ...
<plugin>
```

See [scalatest-maven-plugin](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_maven_plugin).

Comment: The second problem I had was I did not disable surefire. Thanks for your enlightenment